# Email Notification when a new review has been added - Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, e-commerce

This is probably a feature which any one might be looking for. I would like to send an email notification to my store's contact email address every time a new review has been added.

I am planning to do this by making a custom module which on its own as soon as the new review is posted should notify the store owner (on its contact email address).

Now the few things I am stuck with is whether this needs to be run on a cron job or is it capable of running on its own as soon as a new review has been posted.

Also what exactly would be the condition which would check for new reviews and send email alerts. This are just things off the top of my head, but if any one has got a better outline on how to do this, is more than welcome to drop in their suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find an observer or override generic magento class.

Answer (score 5):

As Dick Laurent suggested you can use an observer to notify you by email when a product review is placed.
Looking to see if there is an event after a review is saved I checked:

`app/code/core/Mage/Review/etc/config.xml`

and there is already someone using this event:

```
        <events>
            <review_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <rss>
                        <class>rss/observer</class>
                        <method>reviewSaveAfter</method>
                    </rss>
                </observers>
            </review_save_after>
        </events>
```

So this is the event you are looking for: `review_save_after`

See this Magento wiki link for more information about [Customizing Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

This works if you only want to get notified when a review is posted. If you want more specific/usefull links you might want to override a Magento class from Mage_Review (the controller or the model to store review id and stuff in session.

If you want to include some details about the posted review you can get it from session:

```
$session    = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$data = $session->getFormData(true);
```

Comment: Just want to be clear: there is no such observer for Review so this is not the right way, at least for this request

Answer (score 1):

What i understood from your description is "You want to send a mail confirmation, when a new review is posted".

In each review there will be a form post with review data.
Then you can save review data in db and asynchromously send email notification.
To send email , you can setup SMTP server connection (either in config or via code) and just send mail.

It is all you wanted?

Else post in detail what you need..

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and very dirty fix you can add a 
`mail(to,subject,message)` line to 
app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php 
after the line `$session->addSuccess($this->__('Your review has been accepted for moderation.'));`.

Comment: Try this plugin. FmeAddons provide the source code along with the product package.  It sends email to both customer for review reminder and to the store owners as well when new review is posted.
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/reviews-ratings-booster.html

Comment: What does `main()` do?

Comment: Sorry my bad, that was supposed to be mail. Edited now.

Answer (score -1):

//after $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', array()); add

```
$ratingmsg='';
foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $ratingmsg.='<b>'.$key.':</b> '.$value.'<br/>';
            }
```

//and after  $session->addSuccess($this->__('Your review has been accepted for moderation.'));
//add

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
                    $body='<b>Produit :</b> '.$product->getName().'<br/>'.$ratingmsg.'<br/><br/>Pour valider ce commantaire rendez vous dans <br/>catalogue > commentaires > commentaires en attente';
                    $mail->setToName('name');
                    $mail->setToEmail('mail@gmail.com');
                    $mail->setBody($body);
                    $mail->setSubject('Un nouveau commentaire sur XX');
                    $mail->setFromEmail('contact@site.com');
                    $mail->setFromName("Name");
                    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

                    try {
                    $mail->send();
                    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'mail.log');
                    }
```

Comment: It would be worth adding in an explanation as to what each of the lines of code do in your example, so that people who dont know the code can figure out what each part does